# Vivado HLS: Is it Xilinx specific?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, synthesis

I've been using Vivado HLS (High-Level Synthesis) for the last months and making designs for a Xilinx's ZedBoard.

Now I will probably have to work with a FPGA from another vendor and I don't know if I can still use Vivado HLS to convert C to VHDL. I mean, it generates VHDL code which should run in any FPGA but for example the AXI interface isn't Xilinx's specific? So, can I use Vivado HLs to produce VHDL code for any FPGA?

The reason why I'm asking this here -  and not directly to Xilinx - is because I need a relatively fast answer, so please don't downvote this.

Comment: The Vivado license conditions may have something to say about this.

Comment: Ah yeah, haven't thought about the license.. -_-
But you think it's illegal then? And even if not illegal, would you think it would be possible to generate VHDL code for other FPGA other than from Xilinx?

Comment: I dunno but I wouldn't want to ask Xilinx for support under those circumstances!

Comment: You would probably find some logic uses target specific code - ram blocks for fifos, buffers for IO, etc.  But if the generated files are pure HDL, you should be ok.  Disclaimer, I've never actually used HLS

Comment: Why not start looking into OpenCL?

Comment: The AMBA bus system (AXI, AXI-Lite, AHB, ACE, ...) is from [ARM](http://www.arm.com/products/system-ip/amba-specifications.php). Xilinx bought a license to use it for there IP cores. Before AXI, they used IBM's CoreConnect system (PLB, ...).

Answer (score 1):

According to the Xilinx End User License agreement, section 4.a titled "Special Use Restrictions"...

> 4. Restrictions
>
>    (a) Special Use Restrictions. **No right** is granted hereunder to use 
>      the Software or any Bitstream
>      generated by use of the Software to program or develop designs for
>      **non-Xilinx Devices**...
>
> [[source: Xilinx EULA (March 14, 2014)]](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_1/end-user-license-agreement.pdf)

So I would say, no, you cannot use Xilinx Vivado HLS to even attempt to generate code for another vendor's device.

Comment: Or police will get you and put in jail!